# How do I indicate that the .value of an enum is an unstable implementation detail?

Tags: python, enums

The official Enum HOWTO has [this example](https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/enum.html#planet):

```py
class Planet(Enum):
    MERCURY = (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6)
    VENUS   = (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6)
    EARTH   = (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6)
    MARS    = (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6)
    JUPITER = (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7)
    SATURN  = (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7)
    URANUS  = (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7)
    NEPTUNE = (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7)

    def __init__(self, mass, radius):
        self.mass = mass       # in kilograms
        self.radius = radius   # in meters

    @property
    def surface_gravity(self):
        # universal gravitational constant  (m3 kg-1 s-2)
        G = 6.67300E-11
        return G * self.mass / (self.radius * self.radius)
```

```
>>> Planet.EARTH.value
(5.976e+24, 6378140.0)

>>> Planet.EARTH.surface_gravity
9.802652743337129
```

Suppose I'm doing something like this, and I want to treat the `.value`s—the tuples like `(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6)`—as unstable implementation details of the `Planet` API. I don't want my API consumers to ever rely on them. Instead, I want them to use the properties that I explicitly expose myself, like `.surface_gravity`.

Is there a conventional way to indicate this?

I'm currently just adding a note in the docstring like this:

```py
class Planet(Enum):
    """.value is an implementation detail. Use .surface_gravity instead."""
```

But that seems too easy to miss.

If it were a normal class, I would just make it `._value` instead of `.value`. But here, `.value` is added automatically because I subclassed from `Enum`, and I don't see a way to override that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact value of any enum is nearly always an implementation detail; the reason it's exposed at all is that sometimes it's useful to be able to access it.

There are several ways to de-emphasize it's presence:

- change the `repr()` of that enum class

```py
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s.%s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self._name_)
```

- have a custom `__new__` to make the `value` obviously "wrong" to treat as surface gratity (or whatever) (probably combined with the `__repr__` above):

```py
    def __new__(cls, mass, radius):
        member = object.__new__(cls):
        member._value_ = len(cls._member_names_)
        member.mass = mass
        member.radius = radius
        return member
```

- you could combine with a `dataclass` (which automatically updates the repr):

```py
    @dataclass
    class PlanetData:
        mass: float
        radius: float

    class Planet(PlanetData, Enum):
        MERCURY = (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6)
        VENUS   = (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6)
        # etc

    >>> Planet.VENUS
    <Planet.VENUS: mass=4.869e+24, radius=6051800.0>
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that you have a single class that is doing two things:

1. Storing physical constants
2. Doing a calculation

Personally, I would separate the calculation into a global function that accepts a planet from the enum:

```
def surface_gravity(planet: Planet):
    #...same implementation except use `planet` instead of `self`.
```

Comment: Doesn’t this have the same problem? There’s still nothing signaling to people that they shouldn’t do `Planet.EARTH.value`.

Comment: @Maxpm Yes, I think you are right. This is just what came to mind when reading your question.